# Melhoria e simplificação do código

Tags: c, array

Estou no primeiro semestre da faculdade, e como projeto final o professor pediu para fazer um jogo da forca, eu já fiz meu código porém queria que sugerissem melhorias, ou reportassem futuros problemas do código.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<locale.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<windows.h>
#define T 19
void cenario(void);
void head(void);
void body(void);
void lefthand(void);
void righthand(void);
void leftleg(void);
void rightleg(void);
int main (void){
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"PORTUGUESE");
    int i,j,vidas,exec,op;
    char *palavra;
    char nome[25],letra;
    char lacuna[16]="_";
    char palavras[T][16]={"humanidade","juventude","shopping","supermercado","historia","camiseta","abacaxi","acerola","computador","tartaruga","cachorro","atividade","especialista","entusiasmo","capitalismo","socialismo","desenvolvimento","sistemas"};
//sorteia uma palavra entre as pré definidas    
    srand(time(NULL));
    palavra = palavras[rand()%T];
//preenche as lacunas com o comprimento da palavra
    for(i=1;i<strlen(palavra);i++)
        lacuna[i]='_';
//introdução do jogo
    system("cls");
    system("color b");
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("Bem vindo ao jogo da forca!\nDigite seu nome para começar.\n\nNOME: ");
    gets(nome);
    vidas = 6;
//inicio do jogo
    do{ 
        exec=1;
//limpa o buffer do teclado pra evitar quaisquer erros
        fflush(stdin);
        system("cls");
//faz a parte de interface do boneco
        if(vidas==6)cenario();
        else if(vidas==5)head();
        else if(vidas==4)body();
        else if(vidas==3)lefthand();
        else if(vidas==2)righthand();
        else if(vidas==1)leftleg();
        else if(vidas==0)rightleg();
//printa as lacunas
        printf("\t\t%s\n",lacuna);
        printf("\nDigite uma letra: ");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%c",&letra);
//verifica se a letra digitada está na palavra  
        for(i=0,j=0;i<strlen(palavra);i++)
            if(letra == palavra[i]){
                lacuna[i] = letra;
                j++;
            }
//verifica se acertou a letra na rodada anterior
        if(j==0)
            vidas--;
//verifica se já acertou a palavra inteira
        if(strcmp(palavra,lacuna) == 0){
            system("cls");
            system("color a");
            printf("A palavra era: %s.\n\nVocê ganhou o jogo %s, parabéns!\n\n\n\n",palavra,nome);
            exec=0;
        }
//verifica se já acabaram as vidas do jogador
        if(vidas==0){
            system("cls");
            system("color c");
            printf("A palavra era: %s.\n\nVocê perder o jogo %s, mais sorte na próxima vez!\n\n\n",palavra,nome);
            exec=0;
        }
    }while(exec==1);
//fim do jogo e pergunta se deseja jogar novamente
    system("color b");
    system("PAUSE");
    system("cls");
    printf("Deseja jogar novamente?\n1-SIM\n2-NÃO\n\n");
    scanf("%d",&op);
    if(op==1)
        main();
    else
        return 0;
}
//funções da interface do boneco
void cenario(void){
    printf(" +-------+\n |       |\n |       |\n |\n |\n |\n_|_");
}
void head(void){
    printf(" +-------+\n |       |\n |       |\n |       o\n |\n |\n_|_");  
}
void body(void){
    printf(" +-------+\n |       |\n |       |\n |       o\n |       |\n |\n_|_");
}
void lefthand(void){
    printf(" +-------+\n |       |\n |       |\n |       o\n |      /|\n |\n_|_");
}
void righthand(void){
    printf(" +-------+\n |       |\n |       |\n |       o\n |      /|\\\n |\n_|_");
}
void leftleg(void){
    printf(" +-------+\n |       |\n |       |\n |       o\n |      /|\\\n |      /\n_|_");
}
void rightleg(void){
    printf(" +-------+\n |       |\n |       |\n |       o\n |      /|\\\n |      / \\\n_|_");
}
```

Comment: Pra melhorar mesmo o código precisa ser completamente reescrito. E precisaria entender os objetivos com clareza para ver o que fazer.

Answer (score 2):

Exemplo de melhoria: `if(op==1)` quando for fazer comando de decisão, utilize `{}` fica mais fácil a compreensão, imagine em um programa que você precisa utilizar `for` dentro de `for` dentro de `while`, e assim sucessivamente, logo, o uso das chaves te ajudará na hora de ler e entender o código.
No momento em que você disse `//faz a interface...` abaixo você usa varios `if` e `else if`, uma dica é utilizar assim para melhor compreensão e leitura do seu código...

```
if(vidas==6){
   cenario();
}
else if(vidas==5){
   head();
}
```